# Delphi. Inverted cursor color

Tags: delphi, bitmap, delphi-7, mouse-cursor

I want to use large inverted cross cursor for my app. 
But my code make inverted background of cursor. Cursor still white.

```
var
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  AndMask, Bmp: TBitmap;
  w, h: Integer;
begin
  w := Screen.Width * 2;
  h := Screen.Height * 2;

  // Creation And Mask
  AndMask := TBitmap.Create;
  AndMask.Monochrome := True;
  AndMask.Height := h;
  AndMask.Width := w;

  // Draw on And Mask
  AndMask.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.FillRect(AndMask.Canvas.ClipRect);

//  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(w div 2, 0);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w div 2, h);
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(0, h div 2);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w, h div 2);

  {Create the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.Width := w;
  Bmp.Height := h;
  {Draw on the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, w, h));

  IconInfo.fIcon := true;
  IconInfo.xHotspot := w div 2;
  IconInfo.yHotspot := h div 2;
  IconInfo.hbmMask := AndMask.Handle;
  IconInfo.hbmColor := Bmp.Handle;

  Screen.Cursors[1]:= CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);
  Screen.Cursor:=1;
end;
```

How make background transparent and cursor inverted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  AndMask, Bmp: TBitmap;
  w, h: Integer;
begin
  w := Screen.Width * 2;
  h := Screen.Height * 2;

  // Creation And Mask
  AndMask := TBitmap.Create;
 // AndMask.Monochrome := True;
  AndMask.Height := h;
  AndMask.Width := w;

  // Draw on And Mask
  AndMask.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.FillRect(AndMask.Canvas.ClipRect);

  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Color := clwhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(w div 2, 0);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w div 2, h);
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(0, h div 2);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w, h div 2);

  {Create the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.Width := w;
  Bmp.Height := h;

  {Draw on the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clblack;
  Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, w, h));
  Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := clwhite;
  Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  Bmp.Canvas.MoveTo(w div 2, 0);
  Bmp.Canvas.LineTo(w div 2, h);
  Bmp.Canvas.MoveTo(0, h div 2);
  Bmp.Canvas.LineTo(w, h div 2);


  IconInfo.fIcon := true;
  IconInfo.xHotspot := w div 2;
  IconInfo.yHotspot := h div 2;
  IconInfo.hbmMask := AndMask.Handle;
  IconInfo.hbmColor :=  Bmp.Handle;

  Screen.Cursors[1]:= CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);
  Screen.Cursor:=1;

end;
```